# Guess the secret number java

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

```
package edu.blastermind.model;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * A NumberGuessingGame represents the rules of a simple "guess the number" type game.
 * 
 * @author 
 *
 */
public class GuessTheNumberGame {

    private int highest;
    private int secret;

    /**
     * Creates a new NumberGuessingGame with a secret number between 0 and highest.
     * 
     * @param highest the highest possible number for this game. Must be > 0.
     */
    public GuessTheNumberGame(int highest) {

        // TODO 1: perform a precondition check on the parameter highest
        if (highest <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
            ("highest number must be at least 1");
        }

        this.highest = highest;

        Random rng = new Random();

        this.secret = rng.nextInt(highest + 1);
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if we've guessed correctly.
     * 
     * @param guess our guess (must be between 0 and getHighest())
     * @return true if the guess was correct, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isGuessCorrect(int guess) {

        // TODO 2: perform a precondition check on the variable guess
        if (guess > this.highest || guess < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
            ("Guess must be between 1 and 100");
        }

        return this.secret == guess;
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if our guess is higher than the secret.
     * 
     * @param guess our guess (must be between 0 and getHighest())
     * @return true if our guess is higher than the secret, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isGuessHigher(int guess) {

        // TODO 3: perform a precondition check on the variable guess
        if (guess > this.highest || guess < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
            ("Guess must be between 1 and 100");
        }

        return this.secret < guess;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the highest value in the range of valid guesses.
     * 
     * @return the highest value in the range of valid guesses
     */
    public int getHighest() {
        return this.highest;
    }
}

package edu.blastermind.controllers;

import java.util.Scanner;

import edu.westga.blastermind.model.GuessTheNumberGame;

public class GuessTheNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GuessTheNumberGame game = new GuessTheNumberGame(100);
        int turns = 1;

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Guess a nummber between 0 and 100");
        int guess = kb.nextInt();

        // TODO 4: loop as long as the guess is not correct
        while (!game.isGuessCorrect(guess)) {
            guess++;
        if (game.isGuessHigher(guess)){
            System.out.println("You guessed too high!");
            turns++;
        }
            else if (!game.isGuessCorrect(guess)){
                System.out.println("You guessed too low!");
            }
            int GuessTheNumber = kb.nextInt();
        }
            turns++;

        // TODO 5: in the loop, check guesses and give hints

        System.out.printf("You guessed the number in %d turns\n", turns);
    }
}
```

Hey everyone> I am writing a guess the secret number program in java and I am having some problems.  I keep getting that my guess is too high when I run the program the first time and after I terminate the program and run it again it says my guess is too low.  In the while loop it is suppose to loop as long as the guess is the wrong number which I believe it is doing but I am obviously doing something wrong.  Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you modifying the guess you get from the user ?

Comment: How am I doing that? Please explain

Comment: `guess++` modifies the value of the guess you read in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing your main method. You missed a little bit the variables, adding one to guess. And you were always checking on the first input by the user.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    GuessTheNumberGame game = new GuessTheNumberGame(100);
    int turns = 0;

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    // TODO 4: loop as long as the guess is not correct
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Guess a nummber between 0 and 100");
        int guess = kb.nextInt();
        if (game.isGuessHigher(guess)) {
            System.out.println("You guessed too high!");
        } else if (!game.isGuessCorrect(guess)) {
            System.out.println("You guessed too low!");
        }
        turns++;
        if (game.isGuessCorrect(guess)) break;
    }

    // TODO 5: in the loop, check guesses and give hints

    System.out.printf("You guessed the number in %d turns\n", turns);
}
```

Comment: Have you copied the code as it is? You may have added one curly bracket more than needed. I compiled and ran it.

Comment: I am sorry it was my fault I am trying this out now to see if it works.  Thanks for your help

Comment: I did not add a curly brace after the while loop. Stupid mistake

Answer (score 2):

Your loop checks the correctness of `guess`. And if `guess` is incorrect, you read a new value from the command line and assign it to `GuessTheNumber`, instead of assigning it to `guess`.

I also don't understand why you're doing `guess++`. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I believe he is trying to track the number of guesses that the user given. To the OP: Assign the number of guesses to another `int`.

Comment: @JB Nizet, I was incrementing the number of guesses from the user, so I assign a new value to GuessTheNumber?